# How can I use an editorconfig to prevent underscore prefixes on fields?

Tags: c#, editorconfig

I see a lot of questions about how to *allow* it but I would like to prevent it.

What settings would I put into my .editorconfig file to make all fields be camel_case *without* underscore prefixes (or any hungarian notation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was just working on the underscore rule myself. It seems making [CA1707](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1707) enabled as an error doesn't cut it as it's only breaking on assemblies. I may have missed some more specs in the file but while trying to make it work I found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/VincentH-Net/a88840c96f0083af3064d74e052ad20c) buried in a comment on this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/18354).

```
# Start of NO underscore prefix on private fields
# Define the 'private_fields' symbol group:
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_fields.applicable_kinds = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_fields.applicable_accessibilities = private

# Define the 'notunderscored' naming style
dotnet_naming_style.notunderscored.capitalization = camel_case
dotnet_naming_style.notunderscored.required_prefix =

# Define the 'private_fields_notunderscored' naming rule
dotnet_naming_rule.private_fields_notunderscored.symbols = private_fields
dotnet_naming_rule.private_fields_notunderscored.style = notunderscored
dotnet_naming_rule.private_fields_notunderscored.severity = error
# End of No underscore prefix on private fields
```

To cover *all* fields you'll need to update the accessibilities to:

```
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_fields.applicable_accessibilities = *
```

If you want to make it more accurate to represent all fields for all modifiers, you may prefer this version:

```
# Start of NO underscore prefix on all fields
# Define the 'all_fields' symbol group:
dotnet_naming_symbols.all_fields.applicable_kinds = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.all_fields.applicable_accessibilities = *

# Define the 'notunderscored' naming style
dotnet_naming_style.notunderscored.capitalization = pascal_case
dotnet_naming_style.notunderscored.required_prefix =

# Define the 'all_fields_notunderscored' naming rule
dotnet_naming_rule.all_fields_notunderscored.symbols = all_fields
dotnet_naming_rule.all_fields_notunderscored.style = notunderscored
dotnet_naming_rule.all_fields_notunderscored.severity = error
# End of No underscore prefix on all fields
```

Here's what you'll see for errors:

1. `_someVar` = Prefix '_' is not expected
2. `someVar` = These words must begin with upper case characters
3. `_SomeVar` = Prefix '_' is not expected
4. `SomeVar` = No error

I can't speak to the Hungarian notation part; that seems like it would be a tough one perhaps requiring a custom analyzer or using R# or StyleCop.

Comment: Yeah but how is that describing not underscored? It appears to be describing a camel_case identifier with no required prefix but isn't `_foo` still a valid camel case identifier without a required prefix? It seems like it needs a `disallowed_prefix = _`, or will the `camel_case` rule specifically require a letter to start?

Comment: It's a little weird but not having a prefix defined is like saying no prefix is allowed. Technically, `_someVar` without a prefix defined isn't valid camel case; if you put it in your file you'll see it correctly flags it. Sorry, just realized I left it as camel and you asked for pascal; I think if you change that it should work but I'll also give it a shot in a bit and verify.

Comment: @justin.m.chase, verified it's working as expected for pascal_case. Updated the definition; give it a try.

Comment: You're right it does indeed. Its confusing to me but /shrug

Comment: Sorry I corrected the original question, I did mean camelCase as you intuitively understood I probably meant.

Comment: Also, related to hungarian notation there is another setting which I think handles it, at least in the case of `m_someVar` but maybe not `mSomeVar`: `dotnet_naming_style.notunderscored.word_separator = `

Comment: @justin.m.chase ok I'll look into that. I thought you were probably referring to the kind that prefixes with the type.